# flask-sqlalchemy Get difference between 2 date from database

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

i want to calculate the difference between 2 days from *mysql* database
i have the script like this

```
@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
        def show():

            dura= []

            dates_start=(MyTask.query.get('dates_start'))

            d1=(MyTask.query.with_entities(MyTask.dates_start))

            d2=(MyTask.query.with_entities(MyTask.dates_finish))
             
            dura = d2.date()-d1.date()
            
            return render_template('index.html',dura=dura.days)
```

the html script:

```
{% for output in dura %}
{{ output }}
{% endfor %}
<br>
```

when i run the script it returns an error like this:
AttributeError: 'BaseQuery' object has no attribute 'date'

how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Get date between in two date:

from datetime import datetime

```
date1_ = datetime.timedelta(days=1) # 1 or another number

date2_ = dadtime.timedelta(days=10) # 10 or another number

Model.filter(Model.date_column.between(date1_,date2_),).all()
```

Get differance date between in two date:

```
date1_ = datetime.timedelta(days=1) # 1 or another number

date2_ = dadtime.timedelta(days=10) # 10 or another number

x = Model.filter(Model.date_column>=date1_).all()
y = Model.filter(Model.date_column>=date1_).all()

result_list = [item for item in x if item not in y]
```